# How do you disable the green brightness meter on a Thinkpad T400?

Tags: battery, thinkpad, notifications, osd

I find the green brightness meter that pops up when I am on battery to be annoying. Is there a setting where I can disable this?

Answer (score 2):

There is an "On Screen Display" tab in the advanced video settings dialog.
On that tab, there is an "Enable on-screen dispaly" check box.

To get to the advanced video settings dialog in Windows 7:

1. Right-click on the desktop, select "screen resolution"
2. Choose "Advanced Settings"
3. Click on "On Screen Display" tab

I recommend using [ThinkVantage System Update](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/TVSU-UPDATE.html) to ensure the latest drivers are installed.

- The latest versions have a nicer looking On-Screen Display (OSD) with configurable colors.
- Also there is never any OSD when the screen brightness is altered (I am not sure if this is by design or a bug.)

Comment: thanks for the info: I have XP not Windows 7, but I did find the enable OSD checkbox and disabled it. I would have thought that the enable/disable checkbox for the batter meter would have been in the battery settings, not the display settings, so your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I *love* the new one. So beautiful ^^"